# Is it possible manage xamarin applications version with one file?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I make a xamarin cross app, It have Android and IOS app.

Android app's version setting is possible in AndroidManifest.xml

Also IOS can in Info.plist.

And i need to show splash screen with copyright and version.

If i will do this, I have to manage 4 files AndroidManifest.xml, Info.plist, SplashActivity.cs for Android splash, LauchScreen.storyboard(maybe).

It is not efficient and easy to make miss.

I want to know that is it possible to do that only one file.

For example, make a App.config file in PCL project. Then refer that in 4 files.

Have you any some idea or keyword? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the info.plist and the manifest you will need to manage them separatly ( because they are native and use by platform to know the current version).

But you can have a only one version ( the solution one ) and retrieve it for your android splashscreen getting the application runtime version :

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/12452/get-application-runtime-version

Comment: Thank you OrcusZ. I checked that possible get version from androidmanifest.xml. I will search is it possible in IOS too. thank you

Comment: If is not avaiblable in form don't forget that you can create custom code and call it with dependency injection https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection/

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [xavtool](https://github.com/gabrielrobert/xavtool). It is useful when you want to handle your version across all platforms with a single command.

Typical flow:

```
$ xavtool current
1.0.1 - androidApp (...\test\AndroidManifest.xml)
1.0.1 - iOSApp (...\test\Info.plist)
1.0.1.0 - uwpApp (...\test\Package.appxmanifest)

$ git flow release start '1.1.0'

$ xavtool i
1.0.1: New version: 1.1.0 (...\test\AndroidManifest.xml)
1.0.1: New version: 1.1.0 (...\test\Info.plist)
1.0.1.0: New version: 1.1.0.0 (...\test\Package.appxmanifest)

$ git commit -am "Version bump to 1.1.0"
$ git flow release finish -p
```